# Which web3js version should I use for getting DApp output?

Tags: web3js

I'm using web3js(1.0.0-beta.51) and I wrote the simple code that not returned any output and exact application result which I have expected.

Comment: 1.0.0-beta.34 ...............

Answer (score 0):

Just use the latest beta release 1.0.0-beta.36